# 2013 Ford Fusion - Power Seats only move on one side

Tags: car, seat

My Ford Fusion's driver side power seat has recently been acting up. It will only move on one track as the other track seems halted. This causes a "pivoting" motion when moving the seat forward as it's currently stuck in the most backwards position.

I've done a bit of research on this topic already and want to try a few more things before taking it into the dealership. Here's what I was able to do so far:

- Checked for any obstructions in the track's path
  [image: Track Path]
- Checked for loose wiring
  [image: Connection]

Here's a couple of things I still want to try:

1. The clamp on the seat wiring box was snapped in the center in which I attempted to super glue. This part I assume kept the connections nice and snug. Could this be a loose wiring issue? I had clamped together the part with one hand and attempted to move it forward in which it continued to pivot.
   [image: Wiring Clamp]
2. I wanted to loosen the chair, but it has a "D10" torx socket? I'll have to pickup a Torx socket set to try this out as I do not own one. I hope that by loosening the chair, it will be enough to break out anything or observe anything that might be obstructing the track that I was not able to see since the problematic track is not very visible as it's next to the center console.
   [image: Torx Socket]

Is there anything else that I can try to fix this myself? I do not believe it's a problem with the motor as all motors seem to work fine(2 from what I've found), it's just that it's halting on one side when going forward/backwards.

Apologies in advance for the dirty car!

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

I was able to take out the seat this Christmas Eve. Here are my findings:

1. After taking out the seat, it was much easier to spot the problem. I had a look at the motor first to see what was going on:

[image: Seat Lifted]

2. I then took apart the motor to see what's going on, luckily the problem "fell" as soon as the motor was slightly moved:

[image: Snapped]

3. I then looked inside the motor to extract the piece to see if I can reuse this motor:

[image: Inside Motor]

4. I was able to extract the twisted off piece of metal:

[image: Snapped Metal]

5. Now I have to find a replacement part as the motor seems in good condition. **Anyone have a clue what this part would be called on a 2013 Ford Fusion?** It connects between the seat rail and servo motor:

[image: Servo Part]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Excellent pictures!

Comment: Do these seats have a motor on both rails? Or does one motor do the work for both? Or is one rail passive (not driven)?

Comment: @CharlieRB There is a single motor that powers both rails for the forward/backwards movement I believe. A second motor powers reclining and lumbar support. The motor in question has a green barcode in the pictures above.

Comment: I think you are going to have to get that seat out to be able to access the mechanism. Sounds like the motor is working, but whatever links the two rails has broken or come apart.

Comment: @CharlieRB I think so too, that's this weekend's project and I'll report back with what I find!

Comment: I looked for quite a while to find a diagram but what unsuccessful. If you can post more pictures of what you find would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are going to have to get that seat out to be able to access the mechanism. Sounds like the motor is working, but whatever links the two rails has broken or come apart.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that a piece of metal that connects the motor and rail was twisted right off. I do not know what it's called, and cannot find a product breakdown to identify it.

This comes in part of a repair kit in the **Motor Assy - Seat Adjuster - Part #: MM1179 (14547)** set:

https://parts.ford.com/shop/en/us/small-motors/motor-assy-seat-adjuster-7865863-1

[image: Motor Connector]